# ImageMagick reorients iOS photos

Tags: ios, imagemagick, orientation

I am currently converting images coming from mobiles apps, i.e. iOS, Android and WP.

I use image magick to resize the photos.

Here is my command line:

```
convert -resize 764x764 -strip -interlace Plane -quality 85% img1.jpg img2.jpg
```

It works fine for photos coming from Android and WP however, when I receive it from iOS, the photos are automatically rotated to landscape, even if they are portraits.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Photo orientation can be defined by the images meta-data. Add the [-auto-orient](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option to respect the EXIF data before removing it with `-strip` options.

```
convert img1.jpg -auto-orient \
        -resize 764x764 \
        -interlace Plane \
        -strip \
        -quality 85% \
        img2.jpg
```

Warning from [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient):

> If the EXIF profile was previously stripped, the -auto-orient operator will do nothing.

Comment: Try dropping the `-strip` option, and see if that has any effect. If nothing changes, please run `identify -verbose` on the source image, and post the output in your question.